# Как сравнить объекты по параметрам

Tags: java

Как сравнить два объекта по их параметрам.
То есть, например у меня есть два объекта:

```
Test t = new Test("Vvv","Aaa");
Test t1 = new Test("VVv,"Aaa");
```

Как мне их сравнить по значениям, то есть если два значения совпадают, то true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переопределить в классе `Test` метод [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

```
class Test {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Test other = (Test) obj;
        if (!this.someField.equals(other.someField))
            return false;
        if (!this.anotherField.equals(other.anotherField))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: А как его правильно переопредилить?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сравнить два объекта нужно переопределить метод `equals()`, например, таким образом:

```
public class Test {
            String x;
            String y;

        public Test(String x, String y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            Test other = (Test) obj;

            if(this.x.equals(other.x) && this.y.equals(other.y)){
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```